# Odds in a competition

Tags: probability

I'm trying to work out odds in a variety of competition scenarios.

$1.$ Let's start with the easy one: I've entered a competition. I know that there are 99 other entrants, all with an equal chance of winning a single prize. The odds of winning this must be 1:100. I hope I'm right on that one at least.

$2.$ Now, consider a similar competition. Once again there are a hundred entries and one prize, but this time I have five of those entries instead of one. By my reckoning, buying five entries should mean that I now have a 1:20 chance of winning. Am I still right?

$3.$ Third case: This time we still have a hundred entries. I've only got one of them, but there are five identical prizes, which each will go to different winners. My understanding is that this should also give me a 1:20 chance of winning. This is where I'm not quite so certain of myself. Am I right?

$4.$ Now the reason I'm not so confident about the third case here is because it doesn't really work so well if you combine the second and third cases. So the fourth case is a competition with 100 entries, of which I have 10, and there are 10 prizes. By my reckoning earlier, either of those alone should give me a 1:10 chance to win, but applying them both would mean I've got a 1:1 chance, meaning I'm guaranteed to win. This clearly isn't the case. The odds would be good, but not that good.

So clearly I'm wrong somewhere. But what is my mistake?

Comment: For the first, are you sure of your reasoning? If the type of tournament is a series of $1$ vs. $1$ matches, then your odds of winning the first match are $1$ in $2$, that for your second match are also $1$ in $2$. In general, you are going to have $\lfloor \lg 100\rfloor$ matches, so your odds of winning them all are $1$ in $2^{\lfloor \lg 100\rfloor}$. Perhaps this isn't what you mean though, and you intended a sort of free-for-all competition?

Comment: "Odds" and "probability" are not synonymous. Odds give the ratio of favorable:unfavorable outcomes, whereas probability is the ratio of favorable:total outcomes.

Comment: @trueblueanil - odds are what I was looking for, but probability is close enough. More to the point, I didn't have enough reputation to create a tag for 'odds', so I had to use the 'probability' tag instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, that is 1:100
2. The chance of *not* winning with any of the five entries is 99/100 * 98/99 * 97/98 * 96/97 * 95/96 = 19/20 (not 99/100 * 99/100 ... because you know the entries have lost, not won). Therefore the chance of winning with one is 1 - 19/20 = 1:20 so that is also correct.
3. The chance of *not* winning is 95/100 (as 95 entries lose) = 19/20 so the chance of winning is also 1:20. Correct.
4. The chance of *not* winning is 90/100 * 89/99 * ... * 81/91 = 2.0759...*10^19/6.2815...*10^19 which is approximately 0.3305 so the chance of winning is about 0.6695. Think about step 2: I get the answer a similar way.

Comment: Thank you. I've marked this one as the accepted answer. There were other good answers as well, but I could only pick one. Thank you for explaining it.

Comment: The first one is actually 1:99, not 1:100. Odds are favorable outcomes versus unfavorable, and since there are 99 other contestants with an equal chance, not 100, it should be 1:99.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take the third case. The winners are drawn, one after another.

- For winning the first price, you have a $\frac{1}{100}$ chance of winning it. The lucky entrant of this price is out of the game, after all he has already won (you didn't point out that in the rules very clearly, but I assume nobody is allowed to win twice).
- For the next price (In case you didn't win the first), there are only 99 entrants left, one of them is you: $\frac{1}{99}$ chance to win, $\frac{99}{100}$ to loose.
- Same goes for the next prices. The chance to win the third price is $\frac{1}{98}$, for the forth $\frac{1}{97}$ and for the fith you even have a chance of $\frac{1}{96}$.
- So what is your chance of winning a price? You actually calculate that by asking "What is the chance that I don't win a price?". This chance is $\frac{99}{100} \cdot \frac{98}{99} \cdot \frac{97}{98} \cdot \frac{96}{97} \cdot \frac{95}{96} = 0.95$ (The odds of loosing every single draw).
- Winning a price is the opposite of loosing every single draw, so that would be $$1 - \frac{99}{100} \cdot \frac{98}{99} \cdot \frac{97}{98} \cdot \frac{96}{97} \cdot \frac{95}{96} = 1 - 0.95 = 0.05 = 1:20$$
  Indeed, you are right.

---

If someone who already won a price is allowed to win a second one, your chances get worse: You have more opponents in rounds 2-4.

$$1 - \frac{99}{100} \cdot \frac{99}{100} \cdot \frac{99}{100} \cdot \frac{90}{100} \cdot \frac{99}{100} = 1 - (0.99)^5 = 0.0490099501 = 4.90099501\% < 1:20$$

Not much of a deal, though.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use *odds* loosely, or *chance*; let us stick to *probability.*

Secondly, I take it that where more than one prize is there you mean win **at least** one prize.

$1\; ok, Pr = \frac1{100}$

$2\; ok, Pr = \frac1{20}$

$3\; ok, Pr =\frac1{20}$, also confirmed using complement: $1- \frac{95}{100}$

$4\; not\;ok\;$ here you **must** use the complement: $Pr = 1 - \frac{90}{100}\frac{89}{99}\frac{88}{98}\frac{87}{97}.... \frac{81}{91} \approx0.6695$

---

**ADDED**
If you so prefer, you could do the last as $Pr = 1 - \frac{\binom{90}{10}}{\binom{100}{10}}$

Comment: Thank you. This is a great answer and very helpful. I've accepted another answer, but if I could have accepted two, I would have picked this one as well.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First case: you are correct, 1/100 chance

Second case: yes, you are still correct, 1/20 chance

Third case: yes you are still correct

Odds of getting first prize: 1/100
Odds of not getting first but getting second: 99/100*1/99=1/100
Odds of not getting first two but getting third: 98/100*1/98=1/100
etc.
5*1/100=1/20

Fourth case: incorrect - the problem here is that you combined the probabilities wrong, but that's okay, I was a little confused at first myself.

What you must do is account for the fact that there is a possibility you'll get multiple prizes.

The difficulty in this problem is that each entry can only get one prize.  As a result, we can just assume that once any entry in or out of your possession wins a prize, that entry just goes home and gets drunk. The easiest way to find the possibility that you'll get at least one prize is to find the probability you get absolutely no prizes and subtract that from 100%.

The first prize is given out, and by a 90/100 chance, you don't get it.  The person who did get it went home and got drunk.  We now only have 99 entries.

The second prize is given out, and by an 89/99 chance, you didn't get that one either.  The person who did get it went home and got drunk.  We now only have 98 entries.

By this pattern, we end up with 90/100*89/99*88/98*87/97*86/96*85/95*84/94*83/93*82/92*81/91= 90!/80!/100!*90!

The odds you don't win any prizes at all are 33.04762%
The odds you do win at least one prize is 66.95238%

There you go.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Much appreciated.